# Block animation completes immediately, but CABasicAnimation works correctly with custom animatable property

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, objective-c-blocks, caanimation

There are a lot of related questions, but this situation does not seem to be addressed by any the existing questions.

I have created a view with a custom layer so that one of the properties can be animated. Using the CABasicAnimation class, the animation works correctly.

However, I need a little more control over the animation, such as the ease in and ease out and sequential animations and tried to switch to using block animations. However, when I do that, the animation completes immediately rather than animating over time.

How can I get this block animation to work correctly?

Working animation code:

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"inputValue"];
animation.duration = DEFAULT_ANIMATION_DURATION;

if (flipped) {
    animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.0];
    animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1.0];
    self.myLayer.inputValue = 1.0;
} else {
    animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1.0];
    animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.0];
    self.myLayer.inputValue = 0.0;
}

[self.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animateInputValue"];
```

Animation that incorrectly completes immediately, but `finished` is YES:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:10.0 delay:0.0 options:0 animations:^{
    self.myLayer.inputValue = 1.0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    NSLog(@"done %@", finished?@"and finished":@", but not finished");
}];
```

The CALayer being animated:

```
#import "UViewLayer.h"
#import "YoYouStyleKit.h"

@implementation UViewLayer

+ (BOOL)needsDisplayForKey:(NSString *)key {
    if( [key isEqualToString:@"inputValue"] )
        return YES;
    return [super needsDisplayForKey:key];
}

- (void)setInputValue:(CGFloat)inputValue {
    _inputValue = inputValue;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)context {
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
    [YoYouStyleKit drawUShapeWithFrame:self.bounds input:self.inputValue];
    UIGraphicsPopContext();
}
```

Adding `@dynamic inputValue;` in the custom layer seems to make no difference.

Comment: Are you sure that when you initialize animation, self is not nil and self.myLayer is not nil ? That is usually causing UIView animation to finish immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Do not mix UIKit and Core Animation animations.

Implement like this:

```
[CATransaction begin];

[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^
{
    NSLog(@"done");
}];

CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"inputValue"];
animation.duration = DEFAULT_ANIMATION_DURATION;

if (flipped)
{
    animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.0];
    animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1.0];
    self.myLayer.inputValue = 1.0;
} 
else 
{
    animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1.0];
    animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.0];
    self.myLayer.inputValue = 0.0;
}

[self.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animateInputValue"];

[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: That helps. Is there an elegant way to run sequential animations? Or is it just a matter of starting another CATransaction in the completion block of the first one? Also, what am I missing? WHY wouldn't the `UIView animateWithDuration:` method work in this case?

Comment: UIKit implement their animations internally on top of Core Animation. But since you are not animating any UIKit property, it thinks you have committed no UIKit changes (you haven't) and completes right away. You should not mix CA animations with UIKit.

Comment: For an elegant solution, why not implement a method similar to `+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
                      delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay
                    options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options
                 animations:(void (^)(void))animations
                 completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion` but calling CA API?

Comment: Another option is to chain your animations in some data structure, and use the delegate methods of `CAAnimation` to chain them. This is less elegant than block chaining in my opinion.

Comment: That makes me think I would have been better off making the custom attribute animatable at the `UIView` level rather than the layer? Is that possible? (I know I'm drifting off the question a bit, thanks for hanging in there...)

Comment: See this to wrap your CA animations with UIKit animations: https://github.com/iMartinKiss/UIView-AnimatedProperty

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Leo Natan's answer, as mentioned in the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW12) :

> Custom layer objects ignore view-based animation block parameters and
>   use the default Core Animation parameters instead.

What's more tricky is that you can animate the UIView's own layer properties, provided you change one of the [animatable properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/AnimatableProperties/AnimatableProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH11-SW4).

For custom properties like your layer `inputValue`, you can provide the CABasicAnimation in your layer `(id<CAAction>)actionForKey:(NSString *)key` but it will not use the UIView animation parameters (duration...).

This animation will play when you change the layer property in the UIView block animation, but it will also play when you simply set the value.

The code provided by Leo Natan is the easiest when to animate your layer from the UIView.